# How can i convert from PKCS1 to PKCS8

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

How can i convert a 'PKCS1' 'PEM',which was encoded using 'PemWriter.class' from 'BouncyCastle',into a 'PKCS8' format? 
Also i must specify that i don't want to use any sun.* package.

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure about `PKCS1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put RsaPrivateKey structure defined in PKCS#1 to PrivateKeyInfo structure defined in PKCS#8.

For more details please take a look at my previous answer to similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/23864945/3325704