# EC Key Pair Generation Java code vs JavaKeyStore Explorer Application

Tags: java, cryptography

I created a key pair EC NIST P-256 with the [Java KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/):

[[image: key details[1]]

[image: More Details]

The ASN.1 Format of the PRIVATE key looks as follows:

```
SEQUENCE
{
INTEGER=0
SEQUENCE
{
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER=EcPublicKey (1.2.840.10045.2.1)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER=Prime256v1 (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
}
OCTET STRING, encapsulates:
    SEQUENCE
    {
        INTEGER=1
        OCTET STRING=
            A3 6E C5 71 D3 15 F1 87   ÃnÅqÓ.õ.
            E9 BF AF 78 74 74 67 BC   é¿ xttg¼
            4D A0 69 BF 53 3A C2 E0   M i¿S:Âà
            D8 F6 F5 BC 2E C1 B4 CC   Øöõ¼..´Ì
        TAGGED [0]:
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER=Prime256v1 (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
        TAGGED [1]:
            BIT STRING=
                E6 A9 E2 62 AB 3C 9E 43   ..^Ñ..)X
                E6 A9 E2 62 AB 3C 9E 43   #óþ[æEYî
                E6 A9 E2 62 AB 3C 9E 43   .h®Î..Ë5
                E6 A9 E2 62 AB 3C 9E 43   #óþ[æEYî
                E6 A9 E2 62 AB 3C 9E 43   &.^5.ù¥.
                E6 A9 E2 62 AB 3C 9E 43   #óþ[æEYî
                E6 A9 E2 62 AB 3C 9E 43   #óþ[æEYî
                E6 A9 E2 62 AB 3C 9E 43   .Ëkut.èö
                93                        .
    }

}
```

Then I tried to achieve the same goal via code:

```
 private static final String KEY_BEGIN_PRIVATE = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
 private static final String KEY_END_PRIVATE = "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

 private static void CreateCertificate(BigInteger serialNumber) throws Exception {

 //Create key
 KeyPairGenerator keypairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
 ECGenParameterSpec ecgenspec = new ECGenParameterSpec(curve); //curve = "NIST P-256"
 keypairGen.initialize(ecgenspec);
 KeyPair keypair = keypairGen.generateKeyPair()

 X500Name subject = CreateSubject(); 

 X509v3CertificateBuilder certificate = CreateCertificateBuilder(subject, 
 keypair.getPublic(), serialNumber);

 ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withECDSA")
 .build(keypair.getPrivate());
 X509CertificateHolder holder = certificate.build(signer);

 JcaX509CertificateConverter converter = new JcaX509CertificateConverter();
 converter.setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
 X509Certificate x509 = converter.getCertificate(holder);

 // Encode to pem
 org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 encoder = new 
 org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64(64);

 byte[] derKey = key.getEncoded();
 String pemKey = KEY_BEGIN_PRIVATE + encoder.encodeAsString(derKey) + KEY_END_PRIVATE;

 //Write to disk
 writer = null;
 File file = new File("somepath");
 file.createNewFile();
 writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

 writer.write(pemKey);

 writer.close();
}
```

Key Creating worked fine, no errors and all, but the key looks different in ASN.1, though algorithms are the same. The TAGGED [1] part is missing.

```
SEQUENCE
{
  INTEGER=0
  SEQUENCE
  {
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER=EcPublicKey (1.2.840.10045.2.1)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER=Prime256v1 (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
  }
  OCTET STRING, encapsulates:
    SEQUENCE
    {
        INTEGER=1
        OCTET STRING=
            66 28 18 9F 7C 34 7A 5B   f(..|4z[
            23 F3 FE 5B E6 45 59 EE   #óþ[æEYî
            E6 A9 E2 62 AB 3C 9E 43   æ©âb«<.C
            7B CC 8C 13 D1 26 3B 87   {Ì..Ñ&;.
        TAGGED [0]:
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER=Prime256v1 (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
    }

}
```

I have an application which reads the private key in and some certificates.

With the private Key generated via the java keystore explorer tool everything works perfectly fine, but using code-generated keys and certificates the application fails while reading the private key with :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character d
```

In my opinion it has something to do as how I create the keys and certs, but the exception telling me my base encoding is wrong makes me wondering, as keys can perferctly fine be read with the keystore explorer at import and via openssl comand line.

My Questions are:

- Is there some silly bug or thing I made wrong in the code?
- What does the java keystore explorer make different than I do?

I tried different approaches at how I Base64 encode with different libs, but that didn't make any difference.

Additional: I do NOT have access to the source code of the application reading the keys and certs, so I can't check the implementation. But due to the fact, that other keys work I'd assume that the error is on my side. Keys wont be used in any production or test scenario, so its safe to publish them here, also I modified the values, but that should not make any difference to you.

Comment: The error is that the application is expecting base64 data and isn't getting it. Since you don't have source code and since 'd' is a valid base64 character I can only guess the error is referring to the CR character,  0x0d. Take those out of your base64 data. Maybe get rid of all whitespace.

Comment: Possibly use the Java Base64 encoder in `java.util`. You remove one dependency and it doesn't generate whitespace by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I reviewed my code and found the error. I just forgot to split the encoded string at every 64 position

I changed the way of encoding the keys as following (found here [Converting PrivateKey to pem string without using bouncycastle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23852221/5905718)) :

```
private static String BaseEncode(byte[] data) {
    String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String(data);
    String formatted="";
    for (String substring : Splitter.fixedLength(64).split(encoded)) {
        formatted += substring + "\n";
    }
    return formatted;
}
```